# How to colour a transparent part of an image programmatically in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, transparent

I have an image created and saved manually as a file, which has a shape (e.g. a heart) that is transparent in the image, and the rest of the image has other colour. How to make the transparent shape with a specified colour programmatically in .NET, leaving the rest of the image untouched?

For example, provided is an image, which I want to fill transparent part with a colour.

http://www.sendspace.com/file/an53a1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a flood fill algorithm.
Please take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/floodfillincsharp.aspx

Answer (score 5):

It's transparent.  So draw the background first in the color you want with Graphics.Clear(), then Graphics.DrawImage() to draw the image.

Comment: with that approach he will fill all parts that are transparent ... not good for his needs, if you download the image you'll se that either out of the heart it is transparent...

Comment: Thank for the advice from Hans Passant and Marino Šimić. Is there a way to fill different transparent part with different colour. For example, one colour for inside the heart, and another colour for outside the heart.

Comment: Crappy hosting service, pass.  Okay, use Graphics.FillRectangle for the background painting.  You of course have to know where the heart is located, whichever way you use.

Comment: the way to fill different parts with different colors is called "flood fill", take a look at that codeproject article... sadly it is not an easy task...

Comment: I want to set the two answers as answer, which is not allowed here.